# Counting in a numpy memmap, criterion depends on two fields

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a memmap for reading binary data (> 1000 files of >> 1000 records each)

```
    f  = np.memmap('data.dat', dtype= myFormat, mode= 'r')
```

and know how to count records satisfying a condition depending on a single field (named 'Status' in myFormat):

```
    eval = f['Status'] & 0x20 == 0x20
    nNotEval = np.count_nonzero(eval == False)
```

Another field is used conditionally on eval:

```
    v = calibration * f['V'][eval]
```

Now, how to combine two conditions element-wise? The following failes:

```
    unexpected = (f['Status'] & 0x02 == 0) and (v > 15.)
```

Python protests "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" and suggests "Use a.any() or a.all()", but that is not what I need for

```
    nUnexpected = np.count_nonzero(unexpected)
```

Do I have to iterate? If so, how is the syntax? Something like `for (a,b) in ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a `memmap` issue, or even `count_nonzero` one.  It's about doing the compound boolean operations:

```
unexpected = (f['Status'] & 0x02 == 0) and (v > 15.)
```

This should work better:

```
unexpected = (f['Status'] & 0x02 == 0) & (v > 15.)
```

`and` is a Python scalar operation (short circuiting).  But your expressions produce boolean arrays.  You need to use `&` to join them.

[ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309897/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) (duplicate?)

Comment: Thank you. & works for me. And I should have searched SO for the verbatim error message.

Comment: Sorry, I accepted the answer before proper testing. & has worked for one case, but now I get the following error message `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (682,) (674,)`.

Comment: 682 is the `len` of `f['Status'] & 0x02 == 0`, of `eval`, and of `f['V']`. The length becomes 674 in the operation `f['V'][eval]`.

Comment: I postponed that operation (needed for further evaluation) and found it works: `eval = f['Status'] & 0x20 == 0x20;  v = calibration * f['V'];  unexpected = (f['Status'] & 0x02 == 0) & (v > 15.);  v = v[eval]`.